# Why can't I find Community user on Meta sites?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, community-user, users-page

You can find the Community user on a Main site. For example, on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users):

> [image]

but not on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users):

> [image]

Comment: It seems Community is only listed in the 'reputation' tab. That tab doesn't exist on Meta sites. The user itself does exist: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Comment: I think I know why: because it's be quite high in the list (at least for voters and editors) and unexperienced users might be confused to see it there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm. As [Glorfindel commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324038/why-cant-i-find-community-user-on-meta-sites#comment1059014_324038), Community user is only filtered on `reputation` tab and Metas don't have reputation tab. However there are two work-around:

- You can always click on `Meta User` from the profile of Community user on main site:

  > [image]

---

- You can *force the reputation tab* on Meta Stack Overflow i.e [meta.stackoverflow.com/users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation)**[?tab=reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation)**   and then try to search!

  > [image]

Comment: It's even easier to just add `/users/-1` to the URL...

Comment: @Glorfindel Agree.